# Hash of hashes, how to get keys of the first nested hash

Tags: ruby, hash, nested

I am using a hash of hashes in Ruby, called `MYMOVIES`, as below.

```
    {"127 Hours"=>
       {"title"=>"127 Hours",
       "year"=>"2010",
       "plays"=>1,
       "last_played"=>1300489200,
       "seen_date"=>"19/3/2011",
       "imdb_id"=>"tt1542344",
       "rating"=>"6",
       "omdbapiurl"=>"http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=127 Hours&y=2010"},
    "Zombieland"=>
       {"title"=>"Zombieland",
       "year"=>"2009",
       "plays"=>1,
       "last_played"=>1290207600,
       "seen_date"=>"20/11/2010",
       "imdb_id"=>"tt1156398",
       "rating"=>"7",
       "omdbapiurl"=>"http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=Zombieland&y=2009"}}
```

Now, I would like to get all the keys of the first nested hash (i.e. title, year, plays, ..., omdbapiurl).

I tried with:

```
   mynestedhash = MYMOVIES.first
   puts mynestedhash.keys.to_s
```

But I get the error:

```
    undefined method `keys' for #<Array:0x801c56f8> (NoMethodError)
```

How could I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all inner hashes have the same keys, the following will suffice

```
first_outer_key, first_outer_value = MYMOVIES.first 
first_inner_hash = first_outer_value # change name to show what we have
inner_keys = first_inner_hash.keys
```

If the keys of the inner hashes can be different, you should join them
like Priti and toro2k did in their solutions.

Answer (score 2):

This should do:

```
MYMOVIES.map { |_, h| h.keys }.flatten.uniq
# => ["title", "year", "plays", "last_played", "seen_date", "imdb_id", "rating", "omdbapiurl"]
```

Your code didn't work because the method `first` returns an array, not a hash:

```
MYMOVIES.first
# => ["127 Hours", {"title"=>"127 Hours", ... }]]
```

**Update** If you want to get the keys of the first hash, then you could do:

```
nested_hash = MYMOVIES.first[1]
nested_hash.keys
# => ["title", "year", "plays", "last_played", "seen_date", "imdb_id", "rating", "omdbapiurl"]
```

Or alternatively:

```
_, nested_hash = MYMOVIES.first
nested_hash.keys
# => ["title", "year", "plays", "last_played", "seen_date", "imdb_id", "rating", "omdbapiurl"]
```

Comment: Yes, but isn't there any way to return an hash from the hash (since I created it as hash of hash!)?

    mytmplist = {}
    mytmplist['title'] = ""
    mytmplist['year'] = ""
    mytmplist['plays'] = 1
    mytmplist['last_played'] = mytimestamp
    mytmplist['seen_date'] = myformattedseendate
    mytmplist['imdb_id'] = ""
    mytmplist['rating'] = ""
    mytmplist['omdbapiurl'] = ""
    MYMOVIES[movietitle] = ""

Comment: @MDT What you asked in this post has been answered. Now if you have other need post it in another question. From comment it is not readable what you are looking for.

Comment: `mytmplist = {} 
mytmplist['title'] = "" 
mytmplist['year'] = "" 
mytmplist['plays'] = 1 
mytmplist['last_played'] = mytimestamp 
mytmplist['seen_date'] = myformattedseendate 
mytmplist['imdb_id'] = "" 
mytmplist['rating'] = "" 
mytmplist['omdbapiurl'] = "" 
MYMOVIES[movietitle] = mytmplist`

That's what I wanted to post, sorry about the not-readable post before and thanks a lot for your useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'pp'
h = {"127 Hours"=>
       {"title"=>"127 Hours",
       "year"=>"2010",
       "plays"=>1,
       "last_played"=>1300489200,
       "seen_date"=>"19/3/2011",
       "imdb_id"=>"tt1542344",
       "rating"=>"6",
       "omdbapiurl"=>"http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=127 Hours&y=2010"},
    "Zombieland"=>
       {"title"=>"Zombieland",
       "year"=>"2009",
       "plays"=>1,
       "last_played"=>1290207600,
       "seen_date"=>"20/11/2010",
       "imdb_id"=>"tt1156398",
       "rating"=>"7",
       "omdbapiurl"=>"http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=Zombieland&y=2009"}}

pp h.flat_map{|k,v| v.keys}.uniq
```

**Output**

```
["title",
 "year",
 "plays",
 "last_played",
 "seen_date",
 "imdb_id",
 "rating",
 "omdbapiurl"]
```

Now see why your code didn't work below :

```
h = {"127 Hours"=>
       {"title"=>"127 Hours",
       "year"=>"2010",
       "plays"=>1,
       "last_played"=>1300489200,
       "seen_date"=>"19/3/2011",
       "imdb_id"=>"tt1542344",
       "rating"=>"6",
       "omdbapiurl"=>"http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=127 Hours&y=2010"},
    "Zombieland"=>
       {"title"=>"Zombieland",
       "year"=>"2009",
       "plays"=>1,
       "last_played"=>1290207600,
       "seen_date"=>"20/11/2010",
       "imdb_id"=>"tt1156398",
       "rating"=>"7",
       "omdbapiurl"=>"http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=Zombieland&y=2009"}}

h.first
#["127 Hours",
# {"title"=>"127 Hours",
# "year"=>"2010",
# "plays"=>1,
# "last_played"=>1300489200,
# "seen_date"=>"19/3/2011",
# "imdb_id"=>"tt1542344",
# "rating"=>"6",
# "omdbapiurl"=>"http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=127 Hours&y=2010"}]
p h.first.grep /keys/
#[]
```

Now it is clear that from `#grep` method that Array don't have `keys` method. So try the above code to make it workable.